# 'String' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to parse the output of ros_caffe and republish this in a format ready for speaking. Simon Birrell's node filter_caffe does this but I'm getting the error in the headline. https://github.com/SimonBirrell/filter_caffe

```
import sys
print
print sys.path
print

import rospy
from filter_caffe import filter_caffe_message
from std_msgs.msg import String

Pub = 0

def received_caffe_message(data):
    global Pub
    filtered_message = filter_caffe_message(data)
    if filtered_message:
        Pub.publish(filtered_message)
        rospy.loginfo(filtered_message)
    else:
       rospy.loginfo("No good hit.")
```

I think it's related to this portion of the code:

```
    def filter_caffe_message(caffe_message):
    lines = caffe_message.splitlines()
    if (len(lines) == 0):
        return None
    first_line = lines[0]
    tokens = first_line.split(" ")
    if (len(tokens)<2):
        return None
    raw_probability = tokens[1].split("[")   
    if (len(raw_probability)<2):
        return None
    probability = float(raw_probability[1])
    if (probability>PROBABILITY_THRESHOLD):
        object_list = first_line.split(" - ")[1][10:]
        first_object = object_list.split(",")[0]
        return first_object
    return None
```

This is the exact error I'm getting:

```
    [ERROR] [WallTime: 1491028835.534480] bad callback: <function received_caffe_message at 0xb672e6b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 720, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/filter_caffe/nodes/filter_caffe2.py", line 24, in received_caffe_message
    filtered_message = filter_caffe_message(data)
  File "<string>", line 28, in filter_caffe_message
AttributeError: 'String' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

I understand that splitlines() only works with string objects but I thought that caffe_message was a string?

Thanks!

Will

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258394/%27string%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27splitlines%27/) by [wjvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/22783/wjvh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know anything about this code, but I think I've spotted the bug. The callback is getting `std_msgs.msg.String` objects (note the capital `S`), which are actually a ROS [std_msgs/String](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html) message that wraps a python string, but `splitlines` is only valid on python's built-in `string` type (note the lowercase `s`). You probably need to pass the `data` member from the incoming message into `filter_caffe_message`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wjvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/22783/wjvh/) on 2017-04-01**:
Thanks - I think this could be the issue. However the data member is being passed to filter_caffe_message elsewhere in the code (original question revised to show this) so perhaps it's a problem with how I'm importing or defining the variable or calling the function?

**Comment by [wjvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/22783/wjvh/) on 2017-04-01**:
Solved this - super obvious now. Thanks ahendrix!

```
 lines = str(caffe_message).splitlines()
```